# Report Builder 3.0 Multivalue parameter issue

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Have an issue with creating multivalue parameter in RB3 with SSRS 2008R2. I want to return all the records and then use the parameters to filter down. I have done this through setting the parameter value set as follows:

SELECT
  table.col1
  ,table.col2
FROM
  table
UNION
Select 'Select all', NULL

and then in the main dataset using Field1 = @prmParameter OR @prmParameter IS NULL after the WHERE clause. After selecting the "Allow NULLS" in the parameter, this will return all the rows and then have the parameter drop down to select other table.col1 items and 'Select all'.

A change that is required is to have a Multivalue parameter, but of course the Allow NULLS and Allow Multivalue are incompatible. I have seen a few workarounds, but when I attempt these, I get an error that something is up with my syntax.

What am I missing?

Comment: could you post the syntax error please?

Answer (score 1):

If I could see your query and the error I might have a little more to test with. However, to use a multi value param you have to do something like:

Make sure your report Parameter is selected to allow blank values and allow multiple values (the check boxes in the Parameter).

**QUERY**

```
Select 
 table.col1 ,table.col2 
FROM table
Where ISNULL(table.col1,") IN (@prmParameter)
```

There is a good article [Here](http://www.keepitsimpleandfast.com/2012/03/how-to-pass-null-value-to-multi-value.html)

Hope that helps!